# Unable to back up / rip an encrypted DVD

Tags: encryption, dvd

I have a home server with a bunch of disks to back up all my data (documents, pictures, etc).

I have a bunch of DVDs that I wish to use with post 2010-technology, eg devices without DVD drives. I don't have a DVD drive for my TV, my laptops don't either, and ditto for phones and tablets. The server does have a DVD drive though.

I have one encrypted DVD that I can't back up/convert to streamable. It has 63 titles and 2 are interesting:

```
$ lsdvd |sort -k 4|tail -2
Title: 41, Length: 00:17:49.400 Chapters: 04, Cells: 04, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 03
Title: 42, Length: 01:47:23.967 Chapters: 21, Cells: 28, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 06
```

mplayer (using: `mplayer -dumpstream dvd://N` with N=title number) can dump the title 41, which ffmpeg nicely encodes in whatever I want and the file is playable on VLC. It's the DVD bonus.

I can't do that with title 42, which is the actual movie. I can't dump with mplayer, can't convert with handbrake, can't read with VLC.

I tried to remove the libdvdcss that I had installed from a repo, and instead compile and install from sources, same.

Is this because the DVD is encrypted in a way that VLC can't decrypt? I tried with WinX DVD ripper on my mac, it could successfully convert 5 minutes of the movie itself. I don't want that software, and I don't want to use my mac to convert. I'd like to run this on my server.

Is there a way to dump how a DVD is encrypted? I have increased libdvdcss verbosity and this is the most explicit message I could get (repeated a dozen times):

> libdvdcss error: no key but found encrypted block

mplayer could also tell:

```
libdvdcss error: read error
libdvdcss error: read error
dump: 1404928 bytes written (~0.0%)
dump: 1404928 bytes written to 'stream.dump'.
Core dumped ;)

Exiting... (End of file)
```

*Core dumped* is a weird way of scaring users with a kernel core dump, when it seems it's just a printf message shown when streamdump is finished. Obviously the 1.4MB dumped aren't the whole movie.

Example of the movie played with VLC: one could recognize the Disney castle, but the picture is garbled. The sound is also sluggish.

[image: garbled image]

Same sequence with the extract from the proprietary software:

[image: non-garbled image]

Software used: Debian bullseye with all up to date, and libdvdcss built from source (latest commit of default branch).

Edit: to answer some of the comments, I have tried all 3 modes for `DVDCSS_METHOD` and it didn't help. I did remove the cache in `~` between attempts. I have also tried makemkv, which didn't work, and also seems to require a GUI. I was hoping to get a full headless setup so that I can back up my DVDs completely from the server (I can use X11 forward over SSH but I'd rather have everything scripted and non interactive).

Comment: Try makemkv maybe.

Comment: Also see if setting env var `DVDCSS_METHOD=title` helps.

Comment: Unless you can find the encryption key for that specific movie, you cannot rip it successfully

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the recommendations. I have updated my question to reflect what you asked. @Moab: can you explain (or point to a resource) about how the keys work? I thought that libdvdcss was able to bruteforce, should I understand that this is not a guarantee? The movie of this very DVD is a popular Disney movie, I'd be surprised that nobody could ever play this DVD on Linux... Are there any alternative or improvements to libdvdcss that I could try?

Comment: Have a look at [`dvdbackup`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dvdbackup).